# CS0103 The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, razor

I am trying to Implement [this](https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-comments-aspnet#creating-our-view-files) in an asp.netcoreapp2.2 mvc [project](https://github.com/sabertooth9/MovieBlend/tree/comment-add) but this is giving me error . I Downloaded their code and it complies fine. Here Request is HttpRequestBase WebpageRenderingPage which isn't seems to be available in my Project

I tried to add System.web.dll manually but that doesn't work.
Used Headers in PostDetailController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MovieBlend.Models;
using MovieBlend.Services;
using PusherServer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using System.Web;
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model MovieData
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Model.Title;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var pusher
</script>
@using Humanizer
@using StmlParsing
<style>
    .user_name {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .comments-list .media {
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    }

    h1 {
        color: snow;
        text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    }

    h3 {
        text-align: center;
        color: snow;
        text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    }

    .poster_name {
        text-align: left;
        color: darkred;
        text-decoration: underline
    }

    section {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

    .banner-section {
        background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/373912/pexels-photo-373912.jpeg");
        background-size: cover;
        height: 380px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: inherit;
        background-position: 0;
    }

    .post-title-block {
        padding: 100px 0;
    }

        .post-title-block h1 {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 85px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }

        .post-title-block li {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #fff;
        }

    .image-block {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .footer-link {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background: #222222;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 30px;
    }

        .footer-link a {
            color: #A9FD00;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

    .div-post {
        margin-top: 45px;
    }
</style>
<div id="app">
    <section class="banner-section"></section>
    <section class="post-content-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 post-title-block">
                    <h1 class="text-center">@Model.Title</h1>
                    <h3> @Model.Release | @Model.Language | @Model.Genre</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 div-post">
                    <p>
                        <h6 class="poster_name">Posted By @Model.User_name</h6>
                        <h7 class="poster_name">Posted @Model.Postedate.Humanize()</h7>
                        <br />@Html.Raw(@StmlParser.Parse(Model.Description))
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <p>You Comment</p>
        <form onsubmit="return false;">
            <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Your Name" v-model="comment.Name" class="form-control" />
            <textarea rows="3" placeholder="Your Comment" id="Body" v-model="comment.Body" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="submit_comment()">save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h3><small class="pull-right">{{comments.length}}</small>Comments</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="comments-list">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading user_name">{{com.name}}</h4>
                    {{com.body}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var pusher = new Pusher('7ba0ddfcfbfe565ee8ee', {
        cluster: 'ap2'
    });
    var my_channel = pusher.subscribe('asp_channel');
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            comments: [],
            comment: {
                Name: '',
                Body: '',
                BlogPostID: @Model.Id
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            this.get_comments();
            this.listen();
        },
        methods: {

            get_comments: function() {
                axios.get('@Url.Action("Comments", "PostDetail", new { id = @Model.Id }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme)')
                    .then((response) => {

                        this.comments = response.data;

                    });

            },
            listen: function() {
                my_channel.bind("asp_event", (data) => {
                    if (data.BlogPostID == this.comment.BlogPostID) {
                        this.comments.push(data);
                    }

                })
            },
            submit_comment: function() {
                axios.post('@Url.Action("AddComment", "PostDetail", new {}, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme)', this.comment)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.comment.Name = '';
                        this.comment.Body = '';
                        alert("Comment Submitted");

                    });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Its giving me error in this lines

```
 axios.post('@Url.Action("AddComment", "PostDetail", new {}, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme)', this.comment)
```

and

```
 axios.get('@Url.Action("Comments", "PostDetail", new { id = @Model.Id }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme)')
```

saying Request isn't available

csporj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-MovieBlend-2E001261-E25D-4A77-9170-29F16D765657</UserSecretsId>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CoreCompat.System.Drawing" Version="1.0.0-beta006" />
    <PackageReference Include="Humanizer" Version="2.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="PusherServer" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="StmlParser" Version="1.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Web">
      <HintPath>E:\Downloads\Compressed\System.Web\System.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions">
      <HintPath>E:\Downloads\Compressed\System.Web.Abstractions\System.Web.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `@page` directive at the top of the page to indicate that it is a [razor page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages). The top of the page should look like:

```
@page
@model MovieData
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Model.Title;
}
```

Then you should be able to access the Request property. I do something similar (but just calling Request.Scheme):

```
var _url = '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Data", new { projectId = Model.ID }, Request.Scheme)';
```

Comment: But its giving Null Reference when loading the page


An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore.Views_PostDetail_Index.get_Model()

Stack Query Cookies Headers
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore.Views_PostDetail_Index.get_Model()
AspNetCore.Views_PostDetail_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
+
    ViewData["Title"] = Model.Title;

Comment: Above the 1st line in your .cshtml file have you added @page?

Comment: yes after adding it removes the request not found error but giver this null Reference error

Comment: Do you have a .cs file setting the Model? I've edited the post to include a link to the razor page doc. That has more info on setting models and handling the OnGet

Comment: yes PostDetailController.cs is setting the model.without @page and script for pusher the page loads fine!